# How to create a mysql join query with hierarchical data

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I need to create a join query for hierarchical data across 2 tables. These tables can have unlimited amounts of data and their structures are as follows:

```
group_id      group_name       group_order
   1            group 1            2
   2            group 2            1


field_id    field_name    parent_group    field_order
   1         field 1           1               1
   2         field 2           2               2
   3         field 3           2               1
```

I am currently able to get the correct format of data using 2 select queries with the second query inside a loop created from the results of the first query on the groups table.

The structure of the data I require from the result is as follows:

```
-group 2
      - field 3
      - field 2

- group 1
      - field 1
```

Is it possible to get these results from one mysql query? I have read through the mysql document on hierarchical data by I am confused about how to incorporate the join.

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to think about it in terms of hierarchical data, you should just be able to select your fields and join on your group information. Try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Fields AS F
INNER JOIN Groups AS G 
ON G.group_id = F.parent_group 
ORDER BY group_order, field_order
```

Then you will get each fields as a row with the applicable group, also in the correct group order. Your loop should be able to handle the display you need.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you are correct I was using the wrong logic to try and create the statement

Answer (score 0):

[one method](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

[something that may convince you change your db schema](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)